# ASP NET MVC kendo grid and column bound

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid in which I am bounding columns from one table. But when I want to add a column from another table (`JobItemModel`) data in that column is empty. Please help here. Thanks

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Modus.Presentation.Models.Jobs.JobModel>()
       .Name("#jobs-grid")
       .EnableCustomBinding(true)
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
       .Ajax()
       .Model(model => model.Id(x => x.Id))
       .Read(read => read.Action("List", "Jobs"))
)
.Columns(columns =>
        {
             columns.Bound(x => x.Id).Visible(false);
             columns.Bound(x => x.JobItem).Visible(false);
             columns.Bound(x => x.JobNumber);
             columns.Bound(x => x.Customer.Id).ClientTemplate("#= Customer.Name #");
             columns.Bound(x => x.JobItem.Name); 
             columns.Bound(x => x.JobItem.DateCompletition);
             columns.Command(command => command.Custom("View Details").Click("showDetails"));
```

The model:

```
public class JobModel 
{
     //public virtual int Id { get; set; }
     public JobModel()
     {
          JobItems = new List<JobItemModel>();
     }

     [ModusResourceDisplayName("gp.Job.Fields.JobNumber")]
     public string JobNumber { get; set; }

     [ModusResourceDisplayName("gp.Job.Fields.Customer")]
     public int CustomerId { get; set; }

     [ModusResourceDisplayName("gp.Job.Fields.Contact")]
     [UIHint("CustomerContact")]
     public int ContactId { get; set; }

     public List<JobItemModel>JobItems { get; set; }

     public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }

     public JobItemModel JobItem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your read action that your data source gets data

Comment: Every time you create a `JobModel `, you create a  null list of `JobItems `.  How you populate them?